# XPath: From a node, select all the deepest descendants from the second child on

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, html-parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <shipTo country="US">
        <name><strong>Alice Smith</strong></name>
        <street>123 Maple Street</street>
        <city><hi>Mill Valley</hi></city>
        <state>CA</state>
        <zip>90952</zip>
   </shipTo>
```

***What's the xpath expression to select*** `"123 Maple Street, Mill Valley, CA, 90952"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath 2.0 or XQuery 1.0 you can use

```
string-join(/shipTo/*[position() gt 1], ', ')
```

to get the string `123 Maple Street, Mill Valley, CA, 90952`.

With XPath 1.0 you can select the elements with

```
/shipTo/*[position() > 1]
```

but you would need to construct the string with the host language you use XPath with (e.g. XSLT or a programming language with an XPath API) to iterate over the selected elements and to concatenate the string values.

Answer (score 0):

To get all text nodes from all children of shipTo  which is not name try this:

```
shipTo/*[local-name() != 'name']//text()
```

To get a comma separated list you need to use xlst or xpaht-2.0